# Displaying a string with hidden characters

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I have a test for a class that displays a word randomly chosen from an array.

I'm trying to display the word with several chars hidden

I have taken the string, then converted it to an array of chars, but I'm confused as to where to go from here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class wordTest {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String readString = scanner.nextLine();
         char[] stringArray;


         String [] gamewords = { "dog", "cat", "coffee", "tag", "godzilla", "gamera", "lightning", "flash", "spoon", "steak", "moonshine", "whiskey", "tango", "foxtrot", "ganymede" 
                 , "saturn", "enterprise", "reliant", "defiant", "doom", "galapagos", "jidai", "sengoku"};

        arrayWords wl = new arrayWords();
     // Words w = new Words();
        Word n = new Word();


    int a = 0;
        int b = gamewords.length;


        RandNum rand = new RandNum(a,b);
        n.setWord(gamewords[rand.nextRandomIntegerInRange()]);

        stringArray = n.getWord().toCharArray();
        int blank1 = 1;
        int blank2 = 4; 

        RandNum blanks = new RandNum(blank1,blank2);



        n.setWord(gamewords[rand.nextRandomIntegerInRange()]);


            do{

                int i = 0;
                //scanner.nextLine();
                  for( i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
                      for( i = 0 ; i < blanks.nextRandomIntegerInRange() ; i++ ){

                          stringArray[i] = '*';
                      }
                          System.out.println(stringArray[i]);

                      }


             }while(scanner.nextLine().equals(""));


    }


    }
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? At least show us your attempt in doing something like generating random number and masking a string

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't given clear definition on what you want to do, here I assume for every string, you are randomly masking 2 characters, in pseudo code, it looks like:

```
if inputString.length < 2 {
    mask all character
} else {
    loop until 2 character masked {
        r = random from 0 to inputString.length-1
        if (inputString[r] is not masked) {
            set inputString[r] to mask character
        }
    }
}
```

some hints:

1. to make "inputString" modifiable, make use of a `StringBuilder`
2. Way to check if certain position is masked, you can either simply check if the character in the string == mask character, or you can use a `Set` to keep all masked position
3. In order to find out number of position masked, you can keep a counter, or simply use the size of the `Set` in 2 if you choose to use a Set.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I've found the solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length ; i++) {
    stringArray[blanks.nextRandomIntegerInRange()] = '_';
    System.out.print(stringArray[i] + " " );
}
```

Comment: your solution is not solving what you described in your question